# Basic properties of Lie brackets

Tags: proof-verification, lie-algebras, alternative-proof

I've just started reading what seems to be a fairly elementary introduction book on Lie algebras. I don't know anything about the subject- I picked it up mainly because the preface suggests linear algebra would be the only perquisite- So I'm very sorry if the question is too elementary this is the first time I'm reading mathematics book on my own and trying the exercises just for fun.

I need to show 2 properties from first principles:

1. Show that $[v,0]=0=[0,v],\,\forall v\in V$
2. Suppose that $x,y\in V$ satisfy $[x,y]\neq 0$. Show that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent

Here's how I proved them:

1. Note that $0=v-v$ so $[v,v-v]=[v,v]-[v,v]$ by the bilinearity, and from the property of the lie brackets $[v,v]=0$ we get $[v,0]=0$, the other side should be much the same because of the bilinearity.
2. I will assume $x,y$ are linearly dependent and derive a contradiction. Since $x,y$ are linearly dependent there exist $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $y=\alpha x$ so we can write $[x,y]=[x, \alpha x]=\alpha[x,x]=0$, the reasoning are very similar to 1.

Are these proofs fine? Are there any other proofs for these properties that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine. As a reward, have an [Omer](https://belgium.beertourism.com/belgian-beers/omer-traditional-blond).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both proofs are correct. However, the first statement holds for any bilinar map, not just Lie brackets. In fact, if $B$ is such a bilinear map,$$B(v,0)=B(v,0+0)=B(v,0)+B(v,0)$$and therefore $B(v,0)=0$.

Comment: That's kind of embarrassing understanding that I completed exercise correctly only because it's from a course I already took!
So actually property 2 is also holds for any bilinear map that satisfies the self-orthogonal property, am I right? the special thing about the Lie bracket was supposed to be that it satisfies the jacobi identity and I didn't use it at all (and it wasn't necessary). So another question would be are there bilinear maps that satisfy $\forall v\in V g(v,v)=0$ but doesn't satisfy jacobi's identity?

Comment: I don't know what is that you call “self-orthogonal property”. The **only** thing that I have used was that $B$ is bilinear.